# Capture everything before the next occurrence in a global RegEx search

Tags: php, regex

Let say, this is my string set:

```
HOME
    this
    could
    have
    many
    lines
HOME
    this
    one
    also
HOME
    same
```

How can I get everything **including new lines** before the next occurance of 'HOME' like this: (shortened for the sake of brevity)

```
echo $matches[0]; // first home outputs 'this\n could\n have\n many\n lines\n'
echo $matches[1]; // second home outputs 'this\n one\n also\n'
echo $matches[2]; // third home outputs 'same\n'
// ... HOME(n)
```

What I have tried so far: `/HOME(.*?)\n(.*?)/gU` but I only get was the first line of string:

```
echo $matches[0]; // outputs 'this'
echo $matches[1]; // outputs 'this'
echo $matches[2]; // outputs 'same'
// ... HOME(n)
```

**Note: strings in between two HOME can have variable number of lines, this is what gives me headache**

Comment: This is the snippet of the problem: https://regex101.com/r/6TPpDJ/1 - for clearer view

Comment: I prefer MaxZoom's answer otherwise I'd go with [**`(?:^HOME|(?!\A)\G)\R*\K(?:(?!HOME).+\R*)*`**](https://regex101.com/r/6TPpDJ/3)

Comment: Or `preg_split()` on `HOME` or similar if regex is needed, but `explode()` is better.

Comment: What's wrong with `explode()` solution?

Comment: @revo I still need to use the Regular Expression due to several circumstances, hence the question :)

Comment: Then please like what?

Comment: @revo like expanding it like this https://regex101.com/r/c2VWky/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `preg_split` the following way:

```
 preg_split('~^(?=HOME$)~m', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/VJtZAl).

**Details**:

- `^` - matches start of a line
- `(?=HOME$)` - the positive lookahead checking if the line is equal to `HOME`

So, the code splits at the start of the line that is equal to `HOME`.

With `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` empty matches are omitted from the result. This may be avoided if we add another lookahead: `preg_split('~^(?!\A)(?=HOME$)~m', $s)`.

Comment: Proven to be the most efficient code, after I have adjusted the code to my needs. (y)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of regex you could use  the [preg-split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function

```
$str = "HOME
    this
    could
    have
    many
    lines
HOME
    this
    one
    also
HOME
    same";

$parts = preg_split('/HOME/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($parts);
```

Here is [DEMO](https://eval.in/782665)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex and grab captured group #1:

```
/\bHOME\s+(.*?)(?=\sHOME\s|\z)/s
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TcVEYT/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b` - Assert word boundary
- `HOME` - Match literal text `HOME`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace
- `(.*?)` - Match 0 or more of any character that matched newlines also
- `(?=` - Start of lookahead to match either

  - `\sHOME\s` - Match literal text `HOME` surrounded by white space
  - `|` - OR
  - `\z` - End of input
- `)` - End of lookahead

Comment: the RegEx breakup really helps me. :)

Comment: please don't hesitate to rectify "few vulnerabilities"

Comment: In my answer, I have already taken care of them by using word boundary at start and using `\s` before `HOME` in lookahead to ensure we match `HOME` but not `HOMELY`

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way:

```
HOME\s+(.*)(?=HOME|$)
```

Some guesswork included (I imagine you don't want the **first** line feed ;)

It captures everything after a single line of `HOME` and *it's* linefeed, up to the next `HOME` **or** end of text.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/c2VWky/1).

Comment: Just what I'm looking for.. `/HOME\s+(.*)(?=HOME|$)/gsU` simple and clean , it works like a charm. ^_^

Comment: @FarizLuqman: See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b4l8sf/1) vs. [mine](https://regex101.com/r/xyHX0q/1). Lazy dot matching is not the most efficient solution in this case.